# btn-group create first button too hight

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using `btn-group` to make the `buttons` 100% width, this works well but I get a strange result on the first button, infact if you look at the picture:

[image]

as you can see the first button is too height agains the other two. Why happened this?

This is my code:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified custom-class btn-block">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">First</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">Second</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">Third</button>
</div>
```

This is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rp51o4se/41/).

Comment: Try this
.btn-block+.btn-block {
    margin-top: 0;
}

Comment: go to button and you should remove  class   `btn-block `

Comment: @PUNGIS, please see my answer, since it uses only Bootstrap and not custom CSS for solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for Bootstrap 4, this is how you should do:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="btn-group d-flex" role="group">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Apple</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Samsung</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Sony</a>
</div>
```

See documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/#button-group

> Removed .btn-group-justified. As a replacement you can use  as a wrapper around elements with .w-100.

Comment: Thanks problem fixed, just a question: if you look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rp51o4se/50/ you will see that reducing the window size the first button margin are misaligned against the other two buttons and this is weird, why?

Comment: They have `margin-left: -1px` which causes this, no clue why. You can easily set that to 0px if you want, to make it go away. Strange that Bootstrap didn't solve that, since we're following their documentation.

Comment: ok, now seems to work. Is possible add also some margin like `btn-group`? because with your solution I lose the margin

Comment: Yes of course, this is an example of that: http://jsfiddle.net/rp51o4se/52/

Comment: yep! but only the responsive mode have the margin, is possible to apply also the the full mode?

Comment: Just choose the correct media queries. Here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/rp51o4se/61/ (not very nice with the `!important`-flag, but that's just to make sure that we override bootstraps styles...)

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified custom-class btn-block">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">First</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Second</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Third</button>
</div>

.group-start {
  background-color: #0B3359 !important;
}

#sidebar {
  min-height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.custom-class {
  display: flex;
}

.custom-class .btn {
  flex: 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the `.btn-block` from second of the button. Saw the reference from this link: [See here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24316)

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified custom-class btn-block">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">First</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Second</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">Third</button>
</div>
```